# Why I'm getting 400 error when using file_get_html

Tags: php, html, url

Here is part of my code:

```
include("index.php");
require_once('../simple_html_dom.php');
  $html = file_get_html('http://netbarg.com/tehran/d/62672%2F%D9%81%DB%8C%D8%AA-%D8%A8%D8%B1%DA%AF%D8%B1-%D9%85%D9%86%D9%88%DB%8C-%D8%A8%D8%B1%DA%AF%D8%B1-%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D9%81%D9%88%D9%82-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%B4%D9%85%D8%B2%D9%87-5%2F');
foreach($html->find('a') as $element){
      $htm2=$element->href. '<br>'; 
      echo $htm2;
```

Comment: your url is wrong

Comment: Because the url  you are trying the fetch is not found when opened in browser gives 404

Answer (score 0):

your url is wrong because it encoded two times.  just change your url to this which have been decode once from you url.

http://netbarg.com/tehran/d/c:restaurant/62672/%D9%81%DB%8C%D8%AA-%D8%A8%D8%B1%DA%AF%D8%B1-%D9%85%D9%86%D9%88%DB%8C-%D8%A8%D8%B1%DA%AF%D8%B1-%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D9%81%D9%88%D9%82-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%B4%D9%85%D8%B2%D9%87-5

You can check it with:

```
var_dump( file_get_contents('http://netbarg.com/tehran/d/c:restaurant/62672/%D9%81%DB%8C%D8%AA-%D8%A8%D8%B1%DA%AF%D8%B1-%D9%85%D9%86%D9%88%DB%8C-%D8%A8%D8%B1%DA%AF%D8%B1-%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D9%81%D9%88%D9%82-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%B4%D9%85%D8%B2%D9%87-5/'));
```

Comment: when i use your url ive got this warning:Warning: file_get_contents(http://netbarg.com/tehran/d/c:restaurant/62672/%D9%81%DB%8C%D8%AA-%D8%A8%D8%B1%DA%AF%D8%B1-%D9%85%D9%86%D9%88%DB%8C-%D8%A8%D8%B1%DA%AF%D8%B1-%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D9%81%D9%88%D9%82-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%B4%D9%85%D8%B2%D9%87-5): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request in C:\wamp\www\New folder\simple_html_dom.php on line 75

Comment: i got this error file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\wamp\www\New folder\simple_html_dom.php on line 75

Comment: first make sure you can access in your browser, make sure it's not caused by your network, hosts.

Comment: please tell me about this link ,it even opens in browser.   $html=file_get_html('http://netbarg.com/tehran/d/c:restaurant/62590/');    
foreach($html->find('a') as $element){
      $htm2=$element->href. '<br>'; 
      echo $htm2;